# How to decode COMPUTEDITEMS field on BASKET table

Tags: intershop

I am trying to see how the basket was calculated by inspecting COMPUTEDITEMS field in BASKET table, i see that is base64 encoded and I tried decoding it in VSCode, without the "BASE64:" at start, but it doesn't work, it just outputs some random characters(also tried changing encoding mode of file but didn't help, it was UTF-8). Could you provide example how this field can be decoded.

[image: COMPUTEDITEMS field in BASKET table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an **easier way** to do what you're trying to achieve. When deployed your Intershop Commerce Management server as development environment you can find a cartridge named `dev_basketinfo`. It contains a pipeline called `InspectBasket` with start nodes like `Start` and `DownloadDiagram`. Internally it gets the current basket and displays information about the calculation steps, which rule has been executed, etc.

The **harder way** would be to connect to the database and read the stored value directly. Computed items column can be accessed using standard JDBC means. You need to process the contents as character large object (clob). After that you can do:

```java
StringReader reader = new StringReader(clob.getSubString(BASE64_PREFIX.length(),
            (int)clob.length() - BASE64_PREFIX.length()));
InputStream inputStream = new InflaterInputStream(new Base64InputStream(new ReaderInputStream(reader)));
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
```

[ReaderInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/ReaderInputStream.html) is coming from apache commons.

Comment: In my case it is a production environment and I need calculation details for a specific order that happened in past

Answer (score 1):

The **easy way** described by [Johannes Metzner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8751376/johannes-metzner) is the recommended way. Currently the `dev_basketinfo` does not support reading the computed items of other baskets or orders.

Since that's not suitable for you, you could try to inspect the content by using the [decoding recipe provided by CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Base64(%27A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D%27,true)Zlib_Inflate(0,0,%27Adaptive%27,false,false)). It does in general do the same as above sample code. Just follow the steps.